# Can I do a factory reset to revert back to Windows 7?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu by USB (not dual boot) but I want to revert back to Windows 7 to use windows applications that I need for lab (I've tried wine, didn't work). Can I revert back by just doing a factory reset? I have a Toshiba Satellite A665-S5186 by the way.

Comment: If you used "Erase everything and install Ubuntu" (or something like that) option, then the Ubuntu installer deleted all the partitions including the recovery partition. In that case, factory reset may not work. As I don't have a Toshiba laptop, and I have never tried it, I can't be sure.

Comment: You will have to have the recovery partition for this.  Edit your question and put the output of  `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`.  This will show your recovery partition if it's still available.

Comment: What will it say that shows there's a recovery partition?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to restore from system recovery if Ubuntu hasn't deleted it.

Try this:

1. Turn off your computer and remove everything you have connected to the it (including mouse connected through usb), leaving only the power plug.
2. Turn it On and quickly press and hold the Key 0
3. Continue to hold it until recovery wizard appears (or it doesn't and ubuntu boots)

**Please keep in mind that using this method you will have to reinstall all your applications and data so you better backup your data, it will be erased in this process.**

more info [here](http://support.toshiba.com/sscontent?docId=98082971)